# How to download an entire folder in firebase storge using python?

Tags: python, firebase

I want to download a folder which is inside the firebase storage. But unable to finder a way to download the whole folder as using download option can only be downloaded only 1 file which I know the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the file names are in 1,2,3,.... format. Here you have to add the json account also, by downloading it from firebase settings to use list_files.

```
config={
    "serviceAccount":"abc.json"
}

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()

ab=str(1)    
all_files = storage.child("images").list_files() //Enter the name of the folder    
for file in all_files:             
try:
    print(file.name)    
    z=storage.child(file.name).get_url(None)    
    storage.child(file.name).download(""+path+"/"+ab+".mp3")    
    x=int(ab)     
    ab=str(x+1)  


except: 
print('Download Failed')
```

Comment: Thank you Pavani Jayalath, this code helps me a lot.